# org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor - IllegalArgumentException in class: setter method of property: assessmentBaseId

Tags: java, hibernate, session, object, illegalargumentexception

Stack Trace:

```
 ERROR http-8081-5 org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor - IllegalArgumentException in class: org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.AssessmentBaseData, setter method of property: assessmentBaseId

     ERROR http-8081-5 org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor - expected type: java.lang.Long, actual value: java.lang.Long
```

AssessmentBase.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping default-lazy="false">
  <class name="org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.AssessmentBaseData"
    table="SAM_ASSESSMENTBASE_T">
    <id name="assessmentBaseId" column="ID" type="java.lang.Long" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="native">
        <param name="sequence">SAM_ASSESSMENTBASE_ID_S</param>
      </generator>
    </id>

    <discriminator column="isTemplate" />

    <property name="parentId" type="long" column="PARENTID" not-null="false" />
    <property name="title" type="string" length="255" column="TITLE" not-null="false" />
    <property name="description" type="string" length="4000" column="DESCRIPTION" not-null="false" />
    <property name="comments" type="string" length="4000" column="COMMENTS" not-null="false" />
    <property name="typeId" type="long" column="TYPEID" not-null="false" />
    <property name="instructorNotification" type="integer" column="INSTRUCTORNOTIFICATION" not-null="false" />
    <property name="testeeNotification" type="integer" column="TESTEENOTIFICATION" not-null="false" />
    <property name="multipartAllowed" type="integer" column="MULTIPARTALLOWED" not-null="false" />
    <property name="status" type="integer" column="STATUS" not-null="true" />
    <property name="createdBy" type="string" length="255" column="CREATEDBY" not-null="true" />
    <property name="createdDate" type="timestamp" column="CREATEDDATE" not-null="true" />
    <property name="lastModifiedBy" type="string" length="255" column="LASTMODIFIEDBY" not-null="true" />
    <property name="lastModifiedDate"  type="timestamp" column="LASTMODIFIEDDATE" not-null="true" />


    <one-to-one name="assessmentAccessControl"
      class="org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.AssessmentAccessControl"
      cascade="all" />

    <one-to-one name="evaluationModel"
      class="org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.EvaluationModel"
      cascade="all" />

    <one-to-one name="assessmentFeedback"
      class="org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.AssessmentFeedback"
      cascade="all" />

    <set name="assessmentMetaDataSet" table="SAM_ASSESSMETADATA_T" cascade="all"
      inverse="true">
      <key column="ASSESSMENTID"/>
      <one-to-many class="org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.AssessmentMetaData"/>
    </set>

    <set name="securedIPAddressSet" table="SAM_SECUREDIP_T" cascade="all"
      inverse="true">
      <key column="ASSESSMENTID"/>
      <one-to-many class="org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.SecuredIPAddress"/>
    </set>

    <subclass name="org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.AssessmentData"
      discriminator-value="0">
      <property name="assessmentTemplateId" column="ASSESSMENTTEMPLATEID" />
      <set name="sectionSet" table="SAM_SECTION_T" cascade="all" order-by="sequence asc"
        inverse="true" lazy="true">
        <key column="ASSESSMENTID"/>
        <one-to-many class="org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.SectionData"/>
      </set>

      <set name="assessmentAttachmentSet" table="SAM_ATTACHMENT_T" cascade="all" order-by="createdDate asc"
        inverse="true" lazy="false">
        <key column="ASSESSMENTID"/>
        <one-to-many class="org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.AssessmentAttachment"/>
      </set>
    </subclass>

    <subclass name="org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.AssessmentTemplateData"
      discriminator-value="1" lazy="false" />
 </class>

  <class name="org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.AssessmentAccessControl"
    table="SAM_ASSESSACCESSCONTROL_T">
    <id name="id" column="ASSESSMENTID">
        <generator class="foreign">
            <param name="property">assessmentBase</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <one-to-one name="assessmentBase"
      class="org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.AssessmentBaseData"
      constrained="true" cascade="all" />
    <property name="submissionsAllowed" type="integer" column="SUBMISSIONSALLOWED" not-null="false" />
    <property name="unlimitedSubmissions" type="boolean" column="UNLIMITEDSUBMISSIONS" not-null="false" />
    <property name="submissionsSaved" type="integer" column="SUBMISSIONSSAVED" not-null="false" />
    <property name="assessmentFormat" type="integer" column="ASSESSMENTFORMAT" not-null="false" />
    <property name="bookMarkingItem" type="integer" column="BOOKMARKINGITEM" not-null="false" />
    <property name="timeLimit" type="integer" column="TIMELIMIT" not-null="false" />
    <property name="timedAssessment" type="integer" column="TIMEDASSESSMENT" not-null="false" />
    <property name="retryAllowed" type="integer" column="RETRYALLOWED" not-null="false" />
    <property name="lateHandling" type="integer" column="LATEHANDLING" not-null="false" />
    <property name="startDate" type="timestamp" column="STARTDATE" not-null="false" />
    <property name="dueDate" type="timestamp" column="DUEDATE" not-null="false" />
    <property name="scoreDate" type="timestamp" column="SCOREDATE" not-null="false" />
    <property name="feedbackDate" type="timestamp" column="FEEDBACKDATE" not-null="false" />
    <property name="retractDate" type="timestamp" column="RETRACTDATE" not-null="false" />
    <property name="autoSubmit" type="integer" column="AUTOSUBMIT" not-null="false" />
    <property name="itemNavigation" type="integer" column="ITEMNAVIGATION" not-null="false" />
    <property name="itemNumbering" type="integer" column="ITEMNUMBERING" not-null="false" />
    <property name="submissionMessage" type="string" length="4000" column="SUBMISSIONMESSAGE" not-null="false" />
    <property name="releaseTo" type="string" length="255" column="RELEASETO" not-null="false" />
    <property name="username" type="string" length="255" column="USERNAME" not-null="false" />
    <property name="password" type="string" length="255" column="PASSWORD" not-null="false" />
    <property name="finalPageUrl" type="string" length="1023" column="FINALPAGEURL" not-null="false" />
    <property name="markForReview" type="integer" column="MARKFORREVIEW" not-null="false" />


  </class>

  <class name="org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.EvaluationModel"
    table="SAM_ASSESSEVALUATION_T">
    <id name="id" column="ASSESSMENTID">
        <generator class="foreign">
            <param name="property">assessmentBase</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <one-to-one name="assessmentBase"
      class="org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.AssessmentBaseData"
      constrained="true" cascade="all" />
    <property name="evaluationComponents" type="string" length="255" column="EVALUATIONCOMPONENTS" not-null="false" />
    <property name="scoringType" type="integer" column="SCORINGTYPE" not-null="false" />
    <property name="numericModelId" type="string" length="255" column="NUMERICMODELID" not-null="false" />
    <property name="fixedTotalScore" type="integer" column="FIXEDTOTALSCORE" not-null="false" />
    <property name="gradeAvailable" type="integer" column="GRADEAVAILABLE" not-null="false" />
    <property name="isStudentIdPublic" type="integer" column="ISSTUDENTIDPUBLIC" not-null="false" />
    <property name="anonymousGrading" type="integer" column="ANONYMOUSGRADING" not-null="false" />
    <property name="autoScoring" type="integer" column="AUTOSCORING" not-null="false" />
    <property name="toGradeBook" type="string" length="255" column="TOGRADEBOOK" not-null="false" />
  </class>

  <class name="org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.AssessmentMetaData"
    table="SAM_ASSESSMETADATA_T">
    <id name="id" column="ASSESSMENTMETADATAID" type="java.lang.Long" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="native">
        <param name="sequence">SAM_ASSESSMETADATA_ID_S</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="assessment" class="org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.AssessmentBaseData"
      column="ASSESSMENTID" not-null="true" />
    <property name="label" type="string" length="255" column="LABEL" not-null="true" />
    <property name="entry" type="string" length="255" column="ENTRY" not-null="false" />
  </class>

  <class name="org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.AssessmentFeedback"
    table="SAM_ASSESSFEEDBACK_T">
    <id name="id" column="ASSESSMENTID">
        <generator class="foreign">
            <param name="property">assessmentBase</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <one-to-one name="assessmentBase"
      class="org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.AssessmentBaseData"
      constrained="true" cascade="all" />
    <property name="feedbackDelivery" type="integer" column="FEEDBACKDELIVERY" not-null="false" />
    <property name="feedbackAuthoring" type="integer" column="FEEDBACKAUTHORING" not-null="false" />
    <property name="editComponents" type="integer" column="EDITCOMPONENTS" not-null="false" />
    <property name="showQuestionText" type="boolean" column="SHOWQUESTIONTEXT" not-null="false" />
    <property name="showStudentResponse" type="boolean" column="SHOWSTUDENTRESPONSE" not-null="false" />
    <property name="showCorrectResponse" type="boolean" column="SHOWCORRECTRESPONSE" not-null="false" />
    <property name="showStudentScore" type="boolean" column="SHOWSTUDENTSCORE" not-null="false" />
    <property name="showStudentQuestionScore" type="boolean" column="SHOWSTUDENTQUESTIONSCORE" not-null="false" />
    <property name="showQuestionLevelFeedback" type="boolean" column="SHOWQUESTIONLEVELFEEDBACK" not-null="false" />
    <property name="showSelectionLevelFeedback" type="boolean" column="SHOWSELECTIONLEVELFEEDBACK" not-null="false" />
    <property name="showGraderComments" type="boolean" column="SHOWGRADERCOMMENTS" not-null="false" />
    <property name="showStatistics" type="boolean" column="SHOWSTATISTICS" not-null="false" />


  </class>

  <class name="org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.SectionData" table="SAM_SECTION_T">
    <id name="sectionId" column="SECTIONID" type="java.lang.Long" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="native">
        <param name="sequence">SAM_SECTION_ID_S</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="assessment"
      class="org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.AssessmentData"
      column="ASSESSMENTID" not-null="true" />
    <property name="duration" type="integer" column="DURATION" not-null="false" />
    <property name="sequence" type="integer" column="SEQUENCE" not-null="false" />
    <property name="title" type="string" length="255" column="TITLE" not-null="false" />
    <property name="description" type="string" length="4000" column="DESCRIPTION" not-null="false" />
    <property name="typeId" type="long" column="TYPEID" not-null="false" />
    <property name="status" type="integer" column="STATUS" not-null="true" />
    <property name="createdBy" type="string" length="255" column="CREATEDBY" not-null="true" />
    <property name="createdDate" type="timestamp" column="CREATEDDATE" not-null="true" />
    <property name="lastModifiedBy" type="string" length="255" column="LASTMODIFIEDBY" not-null="true" />
    <property name="lastModifiedDate" type="timestamp" column="LASTMODIFIEDDATE" not-null="true" />

    <set name="itemSet" table="SAM_ITEM_T" cascade="all" order-by="sequence asc"
      inverse="true" lazy="false">
      <key column="SECTIONID"/>
      <one-to-many class="org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.ItemData"/>
    </set>

    <set name="sectionMetaDataSet" table="SAM_SECTIONMETADATA_T" cascade="all"
      inverse="true">
      <key column="SECTIONID"/>
      <one-to-many class="org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.SectionMetaData"/>
    </set>

    <set name="sectionAttachmentSet" table="SAM_ATTACHMENT_T" cascade="all" order-by="createdDate asc"
      inverse="true" lazy="false">
      <key column="SECTIONID"/>
      <one-to-many class="org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.SectionAttachment"/>
    </set>
  </class>

  <class name="org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.SectionMetaData"
    table="SAM_SECTIONMETADATA_T">
    <id name="id" column="SECTIONMETADATAID" type="java.lang.Long" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="native">
        <param name="sequence">SAM_SECTIONMETADATA_ID_S</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="section" class="org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.SectionData"
      column="SECTIONID" not-null="true" />
    <property name="label" type="string" length="255" column="LABEL" not-null="true" />
    <property name="entry" type="string" length="255" column="ENTRY" not-null="false" />
  </class>


  <class name="org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.SecuredIPAddress"
    table="SAM_SECUREDIP_T">
    <id name="id" column="IPADDRESSID" type="java.lang.Long" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="native">
        <param name="sequence">SAM_SECUREDIP_ID_S</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="assessment"
      class="org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.AssessmentBaseData"
      column="ASSESSMENTID" not-null="true" />
    <property name="hostname" type="string" length="255" column="HOSTNAME" not-null="false" />
    <property name="ipAddress" type="string" length="255" column="IPADDRESS" not-null="false" />
  </class>


  <class name="org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.AssesmentSummary" table="sam_assessmentgrading_summary">
  <id name="id" column="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
  <generator class="native">
   <param name="sequence">SAM_GRADING_SEQ</param>
  </generator>
  </id> 
  <property name="agentId" column="USER_ID" type="java.lang.String"></property>
  <property name="assesmentId" column="PUBLISHEDASSESSMENTID" type="java.lang.String"></property>

    <property name="score" column="FINAL_SCORE" type="java.lang.Double"></property>
     <property name="percentage" column="PERCENTAGE" type="java.lang.String"></property>
      <property name="timeSpent" column="TIMEELAPSED" type="java.lang.Long"></property>
       <property name="attemptedDate" column="ATTEMPTED_DATE" type="java.util.Date"></property>
        <property name="submittedDate" column="SUBMISSION_DATE" type="java.util.Date"></property>
    <property name="sectionId" column="SECTION_ID" type="java.lang.Integer"></property>
  </class>



    <class name="org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.Lessons"
        table="MELETE_LESSON_UNIQUE">
        <id name="id" column="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <generator class="native">
                <param name="sequence">LESSON_UNIQUE_SQE</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <property name="siteId" column="COURSEID" type="java.lang.String"></property>
        <property name="moduleId" column="MODULEID" type="java.lang.Integer"></property>
        <property name="sectionId" column="LESSONID" type="java.lang.Integer"></property>
    </class>



    <class name="org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.MeleteModule" table="MELETE_MODULE">
        <id name="module_Id" column="MODULE_ID" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <generator class="native">
                <param name="sequence">MELETE_MODULE_SEQ</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <one-to-one name="meletecoursemodule"
      class="org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.Melete_Course_Module"
      constrained="true" cascade="all" />
            <property name="version" column="VERSION" type="java.lang.Integer"></property>
            <property name="title" column="TITLE" type="java.lang.String"></property>
            <property name="learnObj" column="LEARN_OBJ" type="java.sql.Clob"></property>
            <property name="description" column="DESCRIPTION" type="java.sql.Clob"></property>
            <property name="keywords" column="KEYWORDS" type="java.lang.String"></property>
            <property name="created_by_Fname" column="CREATED_BY_FNAME" type="java.lang.String"></property>
            <property name="created_by_Lname" column="CREATED_BY_LNAME" type="java.lang.String"></property>
            <property name="userId" column="USER_ID" type="java.lang.String"></property>
            <property name="modified_by_Fname" column="MODIFIED_BY_FNAME" type="java.lang.String"></property>
            <property name="modified_by_Lname" column="MODIFIED_BY_LNAME" type="java.lang.String"></property>
            <property name="institute" column="INSTITUTE" type="java.lang.String"></property>
            <property name="whats_Next" column="WHATS_NEXT" type="java.sql.Clob"></property>
            <property name="creation_Date" column="CREATION_DATE" type="java.util.Date"></property>
            <property name="modification_Date" column="MODIFICATION_DATE" type="java.util.Date"></property>
            <property name="seq_Xml" column="SEQ_XML" type="java.sql.Clob"></property>
            <property name="courseName" column="COURSENAME" type="java.lang.String"></property>
            <property name="courseId" column="COURSEID" type="java.lang.String"></property>
            <property name="name" column="NAME" type="java.lang.String"></property>
            <property name="lessons" column="LESSONS" type="java.lang.String"></property>
            <property name="credits" column="CREDITS" type="java.lang.String"></property>
            <property name="content" column="CONTENT" type="java.lang.String"></property>
            <property name="rt_Dt" column="RT_DT" type="java.util.Date"></property>
            <property name="maxt" column="MAXT" type="java.util.Date"></property>
            <property name="course_Level" column="COURSE_LEVEL" type="java.lang.String"></property>

    </class>

    <class name="org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.Melete_Course_Module" table="MELETE_COURSE_MODULE">

    <id name="module_Id" column="MODULE_ID" type="integer">
        <generator class="native">
            <param name="sequence">MELETE_COURSE_MODULE_SEQ</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <one-to-one name="meletemodule"
      class="org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.MeleteModule"
      constrained="true" cascade="all" />
    <property name="courseId" column="COURSE_ID" type="string"></property>
    <property name="seq_No" column="SEQ_NO" type="integer"></property>
    <property name="archv_Flag" column="ARCHV_FLAG" type="boolean"></property>
    <property name="date_Archived" column="DATE_ARCHIVED" type="timestamp"></property>
    <property name="delete_flag" column="DELETE_FLAG" type="boolean"></property>
    </class>


    <class name="org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.Melete_Module_Shdates" table="MELETE_MODULE_SHDATES">

    <id name="module_Id" column="MODULE_ID" type="integer">
        <generator class="native">
            <param name="sequence">MELETE_MODULE_SHDATES_SEQ</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="version" column="VERSION" type="integer"></property>
    <property name="end_Date" column="END_DATE" type="timestamp"></property>
    <property name="start_Date" column="START_DATE" type="timestamp"></property>

    </class>


</hibernate-mapping>
```

AssessmentBaseData.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;


import org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.shared.TypeD;
import org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.ifc.assessment.AssessmentAccessControlIfc;
import org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.ifc.assessment.AssessmentFeedbackIfc;
import org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.ifc.assessment.EvaluationModelIfc;
import org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.ifc.shared.TypeIfc;

public class AssessmentBaseData
    implements java.io.Serializable,AssessmentBaseIfc
{

  private Long assessmentBaseId;
  private Boolean isTemplate;
  private Long parentId;
  private String title;
  private String description;
  private String comments;
  private Long typeId;
  private Integer instructorNotification;
  private Integer testeeNotification;
  private Integer multipartAllowed;
  private Integer status;
  private String createdBy;
  private Date createdDate;
  private String lastModifiedBy;
  private Date lastModifiedDate;
  private AssessmentAccessControlIfc assessmentAccessControl;
  private EvaluationModelIfc evaluationModel;
  private AssessmentFeedbackIfc assessmentFeedback;
  private Set assessmentMetaDataSet;
  private HashMap assessmentMetaDataMap = new HashMap();
  private HashMap assessmentFeedbackMap = new HashMap();
  private Set securedIPAddressSet;

  public AssessmentBaseData() {}


  public AssessmentBaseData(Long assessmentBaseId, String title){
    this.assessmentBaseId = assessmentBaseId;
    this.title = title;
  }


  public AssessmentBaseData(Long assessmentBaseId, String title,Date lastModifiedDate){
    this.assessmentBaseId = assessmentBaseId;
    this.title = title;
    this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
  }


  public AssessmentBaseData(Long assessmentBaseId, String title,Date lastModifiedDate, String lastModifiedBy){
        this.assessmentBaseId = assessmentBaseId;
        this.title = title;
        this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
        this.lastModifiedBy = lastModifiedBy;
      }

  public AssessmentBaseData(Long assessmentBaseId, String title,Date lastModifiedDate, Long typeId){
    this.assessmentBaseId = assessmentBaseId;
    this.title = title;
    this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
    this.typeId = typeId;
  }

  public AssessmentBaseData(Boolean isTemplate, Long parentId,
                  String title, String description, String comments,
                  Long typeId,
                  Integer instructorNotification, Integer testeeNotification,
                  Integer multipartAllowed, Integer status, String createdBy,
                  Date createdDate, String lastModifiedBy,
                  Date lastModifiedDate) {
    this.isTemplate = isTemplate;
    this.parentId = parentId;
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
    this.comments = comments;
    this.typeId = typeId;
    this.instructorNotification = instructorNotification;
    this.testeeNotification = testeeNotification;
    this.multipartAllowed = multipartAllowed;
    this.status = status;
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
    this.lastModifiedBy = lastModifiedBy;
    this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
  }

  public Long getAssessmentBaseId() {
    return this.assessmentBaseId;
  }

  public void setAssessmentBaseId(Long assessmentBaseId) {


    this.assessmentBaseId = assessmentBaseId;
  }

  public Boolean getIsTemplate() {
    return this.isTemplate;
  }

  public void setIsTemplate(Boolean isTemplate) {
    this.isTemplate = isTemplate;
  }

  public Long getParentId() {
    return this.parentId;
  }

  public void setParentId(Long parentId) {
    this.parentId = parentId;
  }

  public String getTitle() {
    return this.title;
  }

  public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    return this.description;
  }

  public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
  }

  public String getComments() {
    return this.comments;
  }

  public void setComments(String comments) {
    this.comments = comments;
  }

  public Integer getInstructorNotification() {
    return this.instructorNotification;
  }

  public void setInstructorNotification(Integer instructorNotification) {
    this.instructorNotification = instructorNotification;
  }

  public Integer getTesteeNotification() {
    return this.testeeNotification;
  }

  public void setTesteeNotification(Integer testeeNotification) {
    this.testeeNotification = testeeNotification;
  }

  public Integer getMultipartAllowed() {
    return this.multipartAllowed;
  }

  public void setMultipartAllowed(Integer multipartAllowed) {
    this.multipartAllowed = multipartAllowed;
  }

  public Long getTypeId() {
    return this.typeId;
  }

  public void setTypeId(Long typeId) {
    this.typeId = typeId;
  }

  public Integer getStatus() {
    return this.status;
  }

  public void setStatus(Integer status) {
    this.status = status;
  }

  public String getCreatedBy() {
    return this.createdBy;
  }

  public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
  }

  public Date getCreatedDate() {
    return this.createdDate;
  }

  public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
  }


}
```

In this loop when i am trying to save object in Session which makes that Exception

```
List pendingAssessList=service.getpendingassessmentData(pendingassessIds,syncDate,siteid);
        for(int i=0;i<pendingAssessList.size();i++)
        {
            AssessmentData ad=(AssessmentData)pendingAssessList.get(i);

            AssessmentData new_a = afq.prepareAssessment(ad, ServerConfigurationService.getServerUrl());        
            openSession.save(new_a);
}
```

assessmentdata

```
public class AssessmentData extends org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.data.dao.assessment.AssessmentBaseData
    implements java.io.Serializable, AssessmentIfc
{


}
```

Comment: Is `AssessmentData` is a subtype of `AssessmentBaseData`? can you provide `AssessmentData` too?

Comment: yes Assessmentdata is subtype of AssessmentBaseData

Comment: Please provide me the solution Debojit i am facing this problem since two days even i can't get the solution

Comment: AssessmentData class i provided is not complete class i provided a snippet for knowing which is subtype of which class

Comment: The last answer of this discussion might help you : https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=940975